# Is there a formula that will search through multiple columns based on a search key?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, average

The current formula is:

```
=averageifs(index(data,,match(B5,Headers,)),index(data,,match("position 1",Headers,)),B3)
```

The function averages total weight for specific positions. It goes through my data sheet's headers to find the column titled "position 1" to find all the athlete who play position B3, but I have athlete who play multiple positions and want to have them included as well.

Is it possible to get it to search through multiple column to find all the athletes who play the same position?

[image: Data sheet with headers]

[image: Formula located at bottom]

[image: Data sheet exercise maxes]

[Headers named range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBxkC.jpg)

[data named range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJuYL.jpg)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @ScottCraner Hi Scott, I am currently using google sheets.

Comment: @player0 Hi, i just attached images of data & datareferences sheet.

Comment: Where is the data range

Comment: @Osm The Data range is located in the 1st picture and i just uploaded a 3rd picture showing the exercises and the maxes there. Let me know if that helps or if you need more info

Comment: Please, add the named rager refrences Header and data, and the formula placement

Comment: @Osm The named ranges have been uploaded now. The formula placement is located in picture 2 in cell D6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets a bit complex, but I think it will give you what you need. It does change the formula from the AVERAGEIFS to the QUERY function.

```
=QUERY(data,"select avg("&LEFT(ADDRESS(Headers,MATCH(B5,Headers,0),4),1)&") where C='"&B3&"' or D='"&B3&"' or E='"&B3&"' or F='"&B3&"' or G='"&B3&"' or H='"&B3&"' or I='"&B3&"' or J='"&B3&"' or K='"&B3&"' or L='"&B3&"' or M='"&B3&"' label avg("&LEFT(ADDRESS(Headers,MATCH(B5,Headers,0),4),1)&") ''")
```

I believe the only thing you may need to change is deleting some of the comparisons to columns. I wasn't quite sure how many Position columns you have in your original sheet.